# Distance between two GPS points (Python)

Tags: python, math, gps

I keep getting the following error with the code below: ValueError: math domain error. I can get the distance between two GPS points with other formulas but not with the formula below. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Gavin

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, acos

#Formula below does not work :(

#JFK
lat1 = 40.639751
lon1 = -73.778925

#DUB
lat2 = 53.421333
lon2 = -6.270075

lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

r = 6373
distance = acos((sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2)) * r)

print(distance)
```

Comment: Can you please give the full exception?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. An extra pair of brackets worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result of `cos` cannot be outside the `[-1,1]` range in real numbers, so the `acos` of a value outside that range is imaginary.  However, you are multiplying by `6373`, resulting in a value way outside `[-1,1]`.  This is the reason for the error.

If you are trying to take the `acos` of a value outside `[-1,1]`, you are either doing something wrong with your math, or you are looking for an imaginary result, in which case you should use the complex version of the `acos`, which is `cmath.acos`.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is not correct.
I believe the formula is
`acos(some_trig) * r`  and not `acos(some_trig * r )`
In conclusion

```
distance = acos((sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2))) * r
```

Comment: Yes. First you calculate arc length between two points on a sphere and then you scale with sphere radius to obtain a distance

Comment: I apologize. Wikipedia backs up your math. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Answer (score 0):

This formula was posted on [Calculating shortest path between 2 points on a flat map of the Earth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868115/calculating-shortest-path-between-2-points-on-a-flat-map-of-the-earth)
and also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

You multiply the values with `r` which tells `acos` to resolve 4435.6 into an angle which is absurd. Cosine could have never produced such a number, greater then 1.

Perhaps you should use put the angle given by `acos` into another formula for circle circumference.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, acos, pi

#JFK
lat1 = 40.639751
lon1 = -73.778925

#DUB
lat2 = 53.421333
lon2 = -6.270075

lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

r = 6373
d = acos((sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2)))
length = d * r

print(length)
```

> 5104.62871371