# Find nearest latitude and longitude points

Tags: geolocation

An question on latitude and longitude...Probably a silly one.

I have a set of latitude and longitudes for various locations.And, I have the latitude and longitude of the location in which I am in.

Now,I have to find the nearest places from my locations from the set of latitudes and longitudes I have. Is thee any special way of calculating it or it is just mere subtraction and checking the difference?

Could you please throw some light on this?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Might want to do a seach of SO - there are plenty of existing answers to this. e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569/calculating-distance-between-2-cities and

Answer (score 13):

It depends on how the points are placed.

For example - if most of the points are in a parking lot, then [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) should work well.

In other cases - [Geodesic Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) needs to be computed. This [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) should help you with more information.

Here is the [conversion](http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpscoordconv.html) from Decimal format to Degree-Minute-Second format and vice versa.

cheers

Comment: Hi Andriyev,

 Thanks for the information. All of my latitudes and longitudes are of the form "13.048869". Is there a way I could convert them to "53 09 02N" format? Sorry if its a way too dumb.

Thanks,J

Comment: @jadaaih - Your lat, long is in decimal format. Updated the response with a link, which is about the conversion you seek.

Comment: I have the similar requirement, I have the list of coordinates for a larger building and I need to find which one of the list is nearest to me. So as per the answer given by @Andriyev Eculidean Distance should work, but it will be really helpful if you (or anyone) throw some more light on same to implement it in code level. I need to implement it in JAVA (Android)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this SQL. it will select then nearest Lat, Lng from your DB entries.

> SELECT id,lat,lng, ((ACOS(SIN(your_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI()
>   / 180) + COS(your_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) *
>   COS((your_long - lng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS
>   `distance` FROM `your_table_name` HAVING `distance` <='10'
>   ORDER BY `distance` ASC LIMIT 0,10

Hope this will help.

Comment: The unit is miles. To get the distance in kilometers, you have to multiply the term "[...]60 * 1.1515[...]" with 1.609344 (which is 1 mile in km) which results in: "[...]60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344[...]".